# How to display data from HealthKit and internet in WidgetKit

Tags: ios, swift, ios14, widgetkit

I'm developing a widget app that coins multiple functional widgets. The problem is fetching data. I want to fetch data from HealthKit to display step counts and fetch weather data.

I'm using just one `Widget` object. I show different widgets by changing the `View` objects in them according to the widget type which is a `String` property.

I can fetch data from EventKit for calendar events, but reminders, health information, and internet fetching is not working on my code. So where am I doing wrong?

My widget provider is looking like that:

```
func getTimeline(for configuration: WidgetConfigurationIntentIntent, in context: Context, completion: @escaping (Timeline<Entry>) -> Void) {
    if let widget = lookUpWidget(for: configuration) {
        let currentDate = Date()
        let midnight = Calendar.current.startOfDay(for: currentDate)
        let nextMinute = Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .minute, value: 1, to: midnight)!

        let type = widget.type
        switch type {
        case "Quotes":
            let entry = MainEntry(date: Date(), type: widget.type!, backgroundImageData: widget.backgroundImage, backgroundHexColor: widget.backgroundHexColor, themeHexColor: widget.themeHexColor, fontName: widget.fontName, text: widget.text)
            let timeline = Timeline(entries: [entry], policy: .after(nextMinute))
                completion(timeline)
        case "Daily Forecast":
            let entry = MainEntry(date: Date(), type: widget.type!, weatherInfo: loadWeatherInfo(), backgroundImageData: widget.backgroundImage, backgroundHexColor: widget.backgroundHexColor, themeHexColor: widget.themeHexColor, fontName: widget.fontName)
            let timeline = Timeline(entries: [entry], policy: .after(nextMinute))
                completion(timeline)
        case "Calendar":
            let entry = MainEntry(date: Date(), type: widget.type!, backgroundImageData: widget.backgroundImage, backgroundHexColor: widget.backgroundHexColor, themeHexColor: widget.themeHexColor, fontName: widget.fontName, calendarEventTitles: loadCalendarEventTitles())
            let timeline = Timeline(entries: [entry], policy: .after(nextMinute))
                completion(timeline)
        case "Countdown":
            let entry = MainEntry(date: Date(), type: widget.type!, backgroundImageData: widget.backgroundImage, backgroundHexColor: widget.backgroundHexColor, themeHexColor: widget.themeHexColor, fontName: widget.fontName, text: widget.text, countdownDate: widget.countdownDate)
            let timeline = Timeline(entries: [entry], policy: .after(nextMinute))
                completion(timeline)
        case "Reminders":
            let entry = MainEntry(date: Date(), type: widget.type!, backgroundImageData: widget.backgroundImage, backgroundHexColor: widget.backgroundHexColor, themeHexColor: widget.themeHexColor, fontName: widget.fontName, reminderTitles: loadReminderTitles())
            let timeline = Timeline(entries: [entry], policy: .after(nextMinute))
                completion(timeline)
        case "Battery":
            let entry = MainEntry(date: Date(), type: widget.type!, batteryLevel: Int(loadBatteryLevel()), backgroundImageData: widget.backgroundImage, backgroundHexColor: widget.backgroundHexColor, themeHexColor: widget.themeHexColor, fontName: widget.fontName)
            let timeline = Timeline(entries: [entry], policy: .after(nextMinute))
                completion(timeline)
        case "Clock":
            let entry = MainEntry(date: Date(), type: widget.type!, backgroundImageData: widget.backgroundImage, backgroundHexColor: widget.backgroundHexColor, themeHexColor: widget.themeHexColor, fontName: widget.fontName)
            let timeline = Timeline(entries: [entry], policy: .after(nextMinute))
                completion(timeline)
        case "Steps":
            let entry = MainEntry(date: Date(), type: widget.type!, backgroundImageData: widget.backgroundImage, backgroundHexColor: widget.backgroundHexColor, themeHexColor: widget.themeHexColor, fontName: widget.fontName, stepCount: loadStepCount())
            let timeline = Timeline(entries: [entry], policy: .after(nextMinute))
                completion(timeline)
        case "Photos":
            let entry = MainEntry(date: Date(), type: widget.type!, backgroundImageData: widget.backgroundImage, backgroundHexColor: widget.backgroundHexColor, fontName: widget.fontName)
            let timeline = Timeline(entries: [entry], policy: .after(nextMinute))
                completion(timeline)
        default:
            let entry = MainEntry(date: Date(), type: "Nothing")
            let timeline = Timeline(entries: [entry], policy: .atEnd)
            completion(timeline)
        }
    } else {
        let entry = MainEntry(date: Date(), type: "Nothing")
        let timeline = Timeline(entries: [entry], policy: .atEnd)
        completion(timeline)
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO - Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to improve, edit and format your questions. 

Without a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) it is impossible to help you troubleshoot.